# How to make application data persist

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, applet

I wrote a simple application in Java by NetBeans. This application takes some strings and stores them in a list. All in a GUI (using Swing).

I would like that when I run file .jar and I store a string and then I close the application,  I would like that when I reopen the application, the program shows me the strings stored before

How can I do?
Thanks to all

Comment: Save the `String`; either to a file in the file-system or to a relational database.

Comment: Your question tags include [tag:applet]. I don't know if this was a mistake, but if you're creating applets you may run into a whole bunch of problems when trying to write data to disk since this may violate Java security settings, especially if the applet is not a "trusted" applet. I would suggest that you not use applets for data output to disk.

Comment: Have you done _any_ research? One google search would have been enough.

Comment: You have any number options, have a look at this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) for more ideas

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8381954/230513).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you'd need to store the data into a file or a similar resource.

Take a look at [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file) for a how-to